# Conditional link in GridView TemplateField with NavigateUrl also conditional ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, conditional-statements, templatefield

I am new to ASP/C# and am trying to create a HyperLink in a GridView Template that will:

a) not display if a database value is NOT true (I have accomplished this)
b) query the SQL database to see if one of two possible fields have values (ISSN or ESSN) - in which case I want to insert that value into a link that queries an external website (PubMed if you are familiar with that).

My ASPX file is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PubMed">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkPubMed" runat="server" Text="S" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Targetlast3Search(Eval("myVar")) %>' Visible='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("Indexed_NIH")) == "True" ? true : false %>' >
       </asp:HyperLink>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Codebehind is:

```
public string Targetlast3Search(object objlast3Search)
{
    Convert.ToString("ISSN");
    Convert.ToString("ESSN");
    char PubMed = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term="ISSN"[Journal]%20AND%20%28%22last%203%20years%22[PDat]%29';

    if ("ISSN" != null)
    {
        return (ISSN in URL);
    }
    else if
    {
        ("ESSN" != null);
        {
            return (ESSN in URL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```